# Get Checkboxfor checked value not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a list of checkboxes in a partial page. When a checkbox has changed it needs to do an ajax call to save the values to the backend and then reload the partial page due to different displays for each item. More rules are added in the cshml depending on selection of the checkboxes as well as other rules that was chosen before this page loaded.

The issue that I'm facing

1. if not checked and user checked the checkbox - this is working
2. if checked and the user uncheck the checkbox - this is not working (value is always true).

This is what the checkboxes look like on the cshtml page:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WindscreenWindowGlassSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.VehicleContentsSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RoadsideAssistanceSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function(){
    checkCheckboxes();
})

////$('input[name="ExcessBusterSelected"]').change(function () {
//$("#ExcessBusterSelected").change(function() {
//    checkCheckboxes();
//});

function checkCheckboxes()
{
    //var excessBusterSelected = $('input:checkbox[name=ExcessBusterSelected]').prop("checked");
    var excessBusterSelected = $('input:checkbox[name=ExcessBusterSelected]').prop("checked");
    var windowGlassSelected = $('input[name="WindscreenWindowGlassSelected"]').is(":checked");
    var vehicleContentSelected = $('input[name="VehicleContentsSelected"]').is(":checked");
    var roadsideSelected = $('input[name="RoadsideAssistanceSelected"]').is(":checked");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Service/SaveExtensionSelected",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ excessBuster: excessBusterSelected, windowGlass: windowGlassSelected, vehicleContent: vehicleContentSelected, roadsideAssist: roadsideSelected }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dvPremBreakdown').load('/Quote/_PremBreakdown');
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            ss.showToast("error", "Error could not set extension", "");
        }
    });
}
```

The value always return true even if checkbox is not checked:
[image]
[image]

If a value is true for the first time it is working:
[image]
[image]

However, when unchecking an item, the values return true when they should be false:
[image]
[image]

Any idea of how this can be fixed? I need to return the real value whether it is false or true.

EDIT -----------------------
This is the chtml side (this is only for one type (Excess buster, but for all 4 checkboxes it is built the same)

```
      <div class="form-group padding-none margin-bottom-none">
        <div class="col-lg-12 padding-none">
            <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label-input padding-none">
                Excess Buster
            </label>
            @foreach (var premBreakdown in Model.PremiumBreakdown)
            {
                if (premBreakdown.schemeType == AusEnums.SchemeQuotedResults.PDEX)
                {
                    if (SessionHelper.GetSchemeTypeIsSelected(premBreakdown.schemeType) == true)
                    {
                        if (validPromotion && Model.Promotion.FreeExtensionList.Contains(AusEnums.SchemeQuotedResults.PDEX.GetHashCode()))
                        {
                            <div class="mobileShow padding-none">
                                <div class="form-group row col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10 CollapseOnAnnual">
                                        <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            Monthly Installment
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            @Model.Promotion.PDWebPremiumBreakdownText
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10">
                                        <label class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            Annual Premium
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            @Model.Promotion.PDWebPremiumBreakdownText
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                                    <div class="mobilehide">
                                                        <label class="ccol-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                                            @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Monthly)
                                                            {
                                                                <label>@Model.Promotion.PDWebPremiumBreakdownText </label>
                                                            }
                                                        </label>
                                                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                                            @Model.Promotion.PDWebPremiumBreakdownText
                                                        </label>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <div class="mobileShow padding-none">
                                <div class="form-group row col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10 CollapseOnAnnual">
                                        <label class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Monthly)
                                            {
                                                <label>Monthly Installment</label>
                                            }
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Monthly)
                                            {
                                                @premBreakdown.FirstInstallment
                                            }
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10">
                                        <label class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            Annual Premium
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                            @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Annually)
                                            {
                                                @premBreakdown.PremiumAnually
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                @premBreakdown.PremiumMonthly
                                            }
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="mobilehide">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                    @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Monthly)
                                    {
                                        @premBreakdown.FirstInstallment
                                    }
                                </label>
                                <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                    @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Annually)
                                    {
                                        @premBreakdown.PremiumAnually
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @premBreakdown.PremiumMonthly
                                    }
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="mobileShow padding-none margin-bottom-none">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10 CollapseOnAnnual">
                                    <label class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                        Monthly Installment
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                        Not Selected
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-10">
                                    <label class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                        Annual Premium
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5  control-label label-inputTop prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                        Not Selected
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mobilehide">
                            <label class="ccol-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6 col-xs-6  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                @if (premBreakdown.PayFreq == AusEnums.PaymentOption.Monthly)
                                {
                                    <label> Not Selected </label>
                                }
                            </label>
                            <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-4  control-label label-input prem-Breakdown-LabelStyle PE-LabelContentHeight">
                                Not Selected
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ExcessBusterSelected, new { @class = "form-control Duty-Of-Disclosure-Checkbox PE-Checkbox PE-Checkbox-NoMargin" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show html generated of your code ?

Comment: @Swati, I've added the chtml side for the Excess buster, the other 4 checkboxes are built exactly the same

Comment: Your jquery code seems ok to me . I think problem is somewhere else . Try to check if there is no two elements with same name , if the htmls are generated are as per your needs or not ..etc  and also you are calling ajax on every  change event maybe it is not getting enough time to update or reset html not sure these are just assumptions .